# View not receiving POST data from image upload page

Tags: python, html, django

I've seen similar questions but can't figure this out, I have a program that upload pictures on a model:

views.py:

```
def upload_pic(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        image_form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if image_form.is_valid():
            image_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('fail')
    return render(request, 'tracker/upload_pic.html', {"image_form": image_form})
```

template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ image_form.img }}
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^upload_pic', views.upload_pic, name='upload_pic')
]
```

Just trying to save to the user model so I can retrieve it later, but I can't access any POST data, I've also tried add `action = "{% url upload_pic %}"` to my `form` in the HTML template, but I get the `NoReverseMatch` error

```
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #model to store the information about the pictures
    class Meta:
        model = ExtendedProfile
        exclude = ()
```

Comment: Please post ImageUploadForm also

Comment: One error I want to point `action = "{% url upload_pic %}"` this is not correct. This `action = "{% url 'upload_pic' %}"` is correct

Comment: Also, that view can't be responsible for displaying the form in the first place, since you just display "fail" when it is not a POST. So you should show the view and URL that does do that, and explain why they are separate.

Comment: Really? Okay so what should that view display then? I've followed tutorials and they've done it this way I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @ArpitSolanki I updated the question with the Image form, I just want to take the info from it. And say update the user profile, I've already extended the user profile but this is causing me issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `action` on your form so it will retrieve the url name.

```
<form action="{% url 'upload_pic' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ image_form.img }}
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

You forgot the `''` on `upload_pic`.

Comment: Totally disagree on the "good practice tip" - having different names for the view and url name certainly dont make things more "readable", it only adds some useless cognitive overhead.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That is not what I think, it's easier when I know I'm using the name attr of the url.

Comment: I had this huge project where none of the url names matched the view functions names, and I can tell you that it was a _major_ PITA to maintain. Anyway: the point was that however  _you_ find it "more readable" it's by no mean a "good practice", just your own preference.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I see, I'll change my answer then, but I've also worked on some hugs projects and never had any problem with that since it's not like I changed the name with something completely random. I keep the url name, just put '_somename' behind. As you saw, upload_pic = upload_pic_detail

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, not at my computer right now but will try it out when I get home. The 'action' attribute always confused me, because I don't know when I should use it. I have other forms without that attribute, so when should in use it?